# How to display only a few cards at a time using core javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I already have a working code for this requirement in jquery which displays the specified number of cards/divs.
For some reason, I have been asked to use pure javascript and I'm not able to achieve it in core javascript.

**Here is my fully working jquery code:**

```js
size_timelinediv = $("#timeline t").length;
console.log(size_timelinediv)//prints 5
var x = 3; //number of cards to be displayed
$("#timeline t:lt("+x+")").show(); //displays the first 3 <t> tags only
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timeline" id="timeline" >
<t style="display:none"><div>Hi</div></t>
<t style="display:none"><div>Hello</div></t>
<t style="display:none"><div>How</div></t>
<t style="display:none"><div>Are</div></t>
<t style="display:none"><div>You</div></t>
</div>
```

Now as per the requirement I need to convert this jquery code to core javascript :

This is what I tried :

```
size_timelinediv = document.getElementById("timeline").querySelectorAll("t").length;
console.log(size_timelinediv)//prints 5
var x = 3;//number of cards to be displayed

document.getElementById("timeline").querySelectorAll("t:lt(" + x + ")").style.display = "block"; //this doesn't work
```

But this doesn't work. It gives the following error :

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': 't:lt(3)' is not a valid selector."
```

How do I achieve the same functionality using core javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS selectors don't have `:lt`. There are many ways to get the *x* first entries of the selected elements, for instance by using `.slice(0, x)` (after converting the node list to an array):

```js
let timelinediv = document.querySelectorAll("#timeline t");
console.log(timelinediv.length); // prints 5
let x = 3; // number of cards to be displayed
for (let t of [...timelinediv].slice(0, x)) t.style.display = "";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timeline" id="timeline" >
<t style="display:none"><div>Hi</div></t>
<t style="display:none"><div>Hello</div></t>
<t style="display:none"><div>How</div></t>
<t style="display:none"><div>Are</div></t>
<t style="display:none"><div>You</div></t>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it works. Will get back to you for further problems that I may face during this conversion of code :)